# NSDictionary with UInt64 values

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsdictionary

Why my `sessionRef` is not taken as String in `NSDictionary`?
The debugger shows the right thing, but seems the `NSDictionary` automatically convert it to int.

Anybody knows the trick?

[image]

> UPDATE:

Though `sessionRef` looks like an integer in the debug print, it really works. Since the code below works when reversing the JSON.

```
NSDictionary *d = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
self.sessionRef = [[d valueForKey:@"sessionref"] longLongValue];
```

Comment: Why do you think it's an `int` instead of an `NSString`?

Comment: @rmaddy As you know it is because Apple does not quote the strings in certain instances causing confusion. Note that this is "fixed" in Swift.

Comment: Based on your updated question, what is your question? You clearly know that the value is a string based on your update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no trick.

The double quotes around string values of an NSDictionary description are displayed only if the string contains space (and a few other special) characters.

Answer (score 1):

The Objective-C `description` method, which `NSLog()` uses, suffers from being to fancy, it does not quote things that it feels don't need to be quoted WRT `NStrings`. Note that `NSDictionary` can not contain an integer, only objects.

Note that the variable errormessage is quoted supposidly because it has an embedded space character. Only Apple knows why they do this.

Comment: `NSDictionary` can contain an `integer` value (eg. `@"myKey" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:123]`), which is part of an object.

Comment: An `NSNumber` is an object, not an integer. `numberWithInt` is a convenience initializer for `NSNumber`.

Comment: I wasn't disagreeing `NSDictionary` can only contain objects, or that `NSNumber` isn't an object, but rather that it's possible to treat an object as an integer. According to the docs `numberWithInt` *"Creates and returns an NSNumber object containing a given value, treating it as a signed int"*. One thing that's not clear to me is what the difference is between using `[NSNumber numberWithInt:123]` or simply doing `@123`,  as they seem entirely the same.

Comment: They result in the same object, the `@123` syntax was added as part go the literal syntax  couple of years ago. See [Objective-C Literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)